# Disable VMWare Fusion "Unity" button

Tags: vmware-fusion

Is there any way to disable the "Unity" button (or indeed the whole bar) in single window mode for VMWare Fusion?

I find myself constantly accidentally hitting this button when using my Windows VM and attempting to hit the close cross in the corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if this was available in versions prior to **VMWare Fusion 7.1.0 Professional**, however in this mentioned version you can do this using the following steps:

1. Right click the toolbar up the top and click "Customize toolbar"
2. Drag all icons from the toolbar to the window opened, including the Unity icon (they'll disappear as you move them)
3. Click Done
4. (Bonus points) Right click again and select "Hide Toolbar" to get rid of that empty grey space

The full screen icon will still be up in the corner, but you have significantly more screen real estate to work with now, and no Unity buttion